# displays = brain.evaluateWithErrorReport(using: dictionaryForVaribles) gives an error unless an as! is added. WHY?

Tags: swift, function, compiler-errors

The line in the view file that has the error is:
    displays = brain.evaluateWithErrorReport(using: dictionaryForVaribles)

The error that I receive is:

```
/Users/Tom/Developer/Stsnford-IOS 10 Course/Calculator_IOS10/Calculator_IOS10/ViewController.swift:166:26: Cannot assign value of type '(result: Double?, isPending: Bool, description: String, errorDescription: String?)' (aka '(result: Optional<Double>, isPending: Bool, description: String, errorDescription: Optional<String>)') to type '(result: Double, isPending: Bool, sequence: String, errorMessage: String?)' (aka '(result: Double, isPending: Bool, sequence: String, errorMessage: Optional<String>)')
```

The compiler says that the fix is to add:
 as! (result: Double, isPending: Bool, sequence: String, errorMessage: String?)

So the line would now look like:
displays = brain.evaluateWithErrorReport(using: dictionaryForVaribles) as! (result: Double, isPending: Bool, sequence: String, errorMessage: String?)

Why won't it work without the as! ?

There are two files to this program which is assignment 2 of CS193P on iTunes.

View File:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Calculator_IOS10
//
//  Created by Theophilos Aravanis on 4/12/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Theophilos Aravanis. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var calculatorDisplay: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var discriptionDisplay: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var varibleDisplay: UILabel!



    var displays: (result: Double, isPending:Bool, sequence:String, errorMessage:String?) {

        get {

            return (Double(calculatorDisplay.text!)!, false, discriptionDisplay.text!, nil)

        }

        set {

            if newValue.errorMessage != " " {
                calculatorDisplay.text = newValue.errorMessage
            } else {
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
                calculatorDisplay.text = formatter.string(from:(NSNumber(value:newValue.result)))
            }
            if newValue.sequence.isEmpty {
                discriptionDisplay.text = " "
            } else {
               discriptionDisplay.text = newValue.sequence + (brain.resultIsPending ? " …" : " =")
            }

            if let varibaleValue = dictionaryForVaribles["M"] {
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
                varibleDisplay.text = formatter.string(from:(NSNumber(value:varibaleValue)))
            } else {
                varibleDisplay.text = " "
            }

        } // end of set
    }

    var userInMiddleOfTyping = false

    var currentDisplay = " "

    var dictionaryForVaribles = [String:Double]()

    @IBAction func digitTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userInMiddleOfTyping {
            let currentlyDisplayedText = calculatorDisplay.text!
            switch digit {
            case ".":
                if currentlyDisplayedText.contains("."){
                    calculatorDisplay.text = currentlyDisplayedText
                }
                else {
                    calculatorDisplay.text = currentlyDisplayedText + digit
                }
            case "BS":
                currentDisplay = calculatorDisplay.text!
                if currentDisplay.isEmpty == false {
                  currentDisplay.remove(at: currentDisplay.index(before: currentDisplay.endIndex))
                    if currentDisplay.isEmpty {
                        calculatorDisplay.text = "0"
                        userInMiddleOfTyping = false
                    } else {
                        calculatorDisplay.text = currentDisplay
                        userInMiddleOfTyping = true
                    }
                }
            default:
                calculatorDisplay.text = currentlyDisplayedText + digit
            }
        }
        else {
            switch digit {
            case "bs":
                break
            default:
                calculatorDisplay.text = digit
                userInMiddleOfTyping = true
            }
        }
    }

  /*  var displayValue:Double{
        get {
            return Double(calculatorDisplay.text!)!

        }
        set {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
            calculatorDisplay.text = formatter.string(from:(NSNumber(value:newValue)))
        }
    }
    var displayDescription:String{
        get {
                return discriptionDisplay.text!
        }
        set {
          discriptionDisplay.text = newValue + (brain.resultIsPending ? " …" : " =")
        }
    } */
    private var brain = CalculatorBrain()

    func showDescriptionDisplay() {
        discriptionDisplay.isHidden = false
    }
    func hideDescriptionDisplay() {
        discriptionDisplay.isHidden = true
    }

    func showVaribleDisplay() {
        varibleDisplay.isHidden = false
    }

    func hideVaribleDisplay() {
        varibleDisplay.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func allClear(_ sender: UIButton) {
        hideDescriptionDisplay()
        discriptionDisplay.text = " "
        calculatorDisplay.text = "0"
        userInMiddleOfTyping = false
        brain.clearAccumulator()
    }

    @IBAction func setVarible(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let symbol = sender.currentTitle!
        brain.setOperand(variable:symbol)
    }

    @IBAction func evaluateVarible(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showDescriptionDisplay()
        if userInMiddleOfTyping {
            brain.setOperand(displays.result)
            userInMiddleOfTyping = false
        }
        if let mathimaticalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            brain.performOperation(mathimaticalSymbol)
        }

        displays = brain.evaluateWithErrorReport(using: dictionaryForVaribles) as! (result: Double, isPending: Bool, sequence: String, errorMessage: String?)


/*        if let result = brain.result {
            displays.result = result
        }
//        if let descriptionLine = brain.line {
//            displays.sequence = descriptionLine
//        } */
    }
}
```

model file:

```
//
//  CalculatorBrain_IOS10.swift
//  Calculator_IOS10
//
//  Created by Theophilos Aravanis on 4/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Theophilos Aravanis. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

func factorial(_ op1: Double) -> Double {
    if (op1 <= 1.0) {
        return 1.0
    }
    return op1 * factorial(op1 - 1.0)
}




struct CalculatorBrain {


    var result:Double? {
        get {
            return accumulator?.0
        }
    }

//    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Use evaluate instead")
    var resultIsPending = false


    private var accumulator:(digit:Double, description:String?, errorMessage:String?)?

    private enum MemoryVarible {
        case operand(Double)
        case operation(String)
        case variable(String)
    }

    private var memorySequence = [MemoryVarible]()

    private enum Operation {
        case constant(Double)
        case nullOperation(() -> Double, String)
        case unaryOperation((Double) -> Double, (String) -> String, (Double) -> String?)
        case binaryOperation((Double,Double) -> Double, (String, String) -> String, (Double,Double) -> String?)
        case equals
    }
    private var operations:Dictionary<String,Operation> =
        [
            "rand": .nullOperation({Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max)}, "rand()"),
            "π" : .constant(M_PI),
            "e" : .constant(M_E),
            "√" : .unaryOperation(sqrt,{"√(" + $0 + ")"},{$0 < 0 ? "Sqrt of negative number" : nil}),
            "cos" :.unaryOperation(cos,{"cos(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil}),
            "∓" : .unaryOperation({-$0},{"-(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil}),
            "x²" :.unaryOperation({ pow($0, 2) }, { "(" + $0 + ")²" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x³" :.unaryOperation({ pow($0, 3) }, { "(" + $0 + ")³" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x⁻¹" :.unaryOperation({ 1 / $0 }, {  "(" + $0 + ")⁻¹" },{ _ in nil}),
            "sin" :.unaryOperation(sin, { "sin(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "tan" :.unaryOperation(tan, { "tan(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "sinh" :.unaryOperation(sinh, { "sinh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "cosh" :.unaryOperation(cosh, { "cosh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "tanh" :.unaryOperation(tanh, { "tanh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "ln" :  .unaryOperation(log, { "ln(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "log" : .unaryOperation(log10, { "log(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "eˣ" :.unaryOperation(exp, { "e^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "10ˣ" :.unaryOperation({ pow(10, $0) }, { "10^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x!" :.unaryOperation(factorial, { "(" + $0 + ")!" },{ _ in nil}),
            "xʸ" :.binaryOperation(pow, { $0 + "^" + $1 },{ _,_ in nil}),
            "+" : .binaryOperation(+,{$0 + "+" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "−" : .binaryOperation(-,{$0 + "-" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "÷" : .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, {_,_ in  nil }),
            "×" : .binaryOperation(*,{$0 + "*" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "=" : .equals
    ]

    mutating func clearAccumulator() {
        accumulator?.errorMessage = nil
        accumulator?.description = " "
        accumulator?.digit = 0
    }

    mutating func evaluate(using variables: Dictionary<String,Double>? = nil) -> (result: Double?, isPending: Bool, description: String) {

        let (result, isPending, description, _) = evaluateWithErrorReport(using: variables)

        return (result, isPending, description)

    }

    mutating func performOperation(_ symbol: String) {
        memorySequence.append(MemoryVarible.operation(symbol))
    }

    mutating func setOperand(_ operand: Double) {
        memorySequence.append(MemoryVarible.operand(operand))
    }

    mutating func setOperand(variable named: String) {
        memorySequence.append(MemoryVarible.variable(named))
    }

    mutating func evaluateWithErrorReport(using variables: Dictionary<String,Double>? = nil) -> (result: Double?, isPending: Bool, description: String, errorDescription: String?) {

         var pendingBinaryOperation:PendingBinaryOperation?

        var calculationDescription:String? {
            get {
                if pendingBinaryOperation == nil  {
                    return accumulator?.description
                } else {
                    return pendingBinaryOperation!.calculationDescription(pendingBinaryOperation!.descriptionOperand, accumulator?.description ?? " ")
                }
            }
        }

        var line:String? {
            get {
                return calculationDescription
            }
        }

         func performOperation(_ symbol:String){
            if let currentOperation = operations[symbol] {
                switch currentOperation {
                case .nullOperation(let function, let nullDiscription):
                    accumulator = (function(), nullDiscription, nil)
                case .constant(let value):
                    accumulator = (value,symbol, nil)
                case .unaryOperation(let function, let unaryDescription, let unaryMemory):
                    if accumulator != nil {
                        accumulator = (function(accumulator!.digit), unaryDescription(accumulator!.description!),
                                       unaryMemory(accumulator!.digit))
                    }
                case .binaryOperation(let binaryFunction,
                                      let binaryDescription,
                                      let binaryError):
                    if accumulator != nil {
                        doAPendingBinaryOperation()
                        resultIsPending = true
                        pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(
                            calculationError:binaryError,
                            mathFunction: binaryFunction,
                            calculationDescription:binaryDescription,
                            firstOperand: accumulator!.digit,
                            descriptionOperand:(accumulator?.description)! )
                        accumulator = nil
                    }
                case .equals:
                    doAPendingBinaryOperation()
                    resultIsPending = false
                }
            }
        }

        func doAPendingBinaryOperation() {
            if pendingBinaryOperation != nil && accumulator != nil {
                accumulator!.description = calculationDescription!
                accumulator!.digit = pendingBinaryOperation!.perform(with: accumulator!.digit)
                accumulator!.errorMessage = "Future enhancement"
                pendingBinaryOperation = nil
            }

        }

        struct PendingBinaryOperation {
            let calculationError: (Double, Double) -> String?
            let mathFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
            let calculationDescription: (String, String) -> String
            let firstOperand: (Double)
            let descriptionOperand:(String)
            func perform(with secondOperand:(Double)) -> Double {
                return (mathFunction(firstOperand, secondOperand))
            }
            func performDecription(with secondOperan:(String)) -> String {
                return (calculationDescription(descriptionOperand, secondOperan))
            }
        }

        func setOperand(_ operand:Double) {
            accumulator = (operand, String(Int(operand)), nil)
        }

        func setOperand(variable named: String) {

            accumulator = (variables?[named] ?? 0, named, nil)

        }

        for item in memorySequence {
            switch item {
            case .operand(let operand):

                setOperand(operand)

            case .operation(let operation):

                performOperation(operation)

            case .variable(let variable):

                setOperand(variable:variable)
            }
        }


        if pendingBinaryOperation != nil {

            return (accumulator!.digit, true, pendingBinaryOperation!.calculationDescription(pendingBinaryOperation!.descriptionOperand, accumulator!.description ?? ""), accumulator?.errorMessage)

        } else {

            return (accumulator!.digit, false, accumulator!.description ?? "", accumulator?.errorMessage)

        }

    }  // end of evaluate with errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple typo. In evaluateWithErrorReport your return value has a "Double?" where as the type for your displays variable includes a "Double" not "Double?".

Comment: I tried that and still got the same error.  It seems that the errorMessage is where the problem occurs.

Comment: I fixed it by changing both  displays.result and accumulator.digit into optionals.  After fixing all the syntax errors that this caused the code compiled with no errors.